# CDF and PDF of Maximum Draw

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

I'm reading some lecture notes on order statistics and I was hoping to get some clarification.

*The highest draw of $z$ draws from the continuous distribution F is given by*

1)$$ F^z(x)$$

Why is it $F(x)$ to the power of z? What does it look like when you multiply a distribution by itself? What would this look like in the case of a uniform distribution for instance?

and,

*The pdf of the highest draw of $z$ draws from the continuous distribution F is given by*

2)
$$zF^{z-1}f(x)(x)$$

What is the intuition behind this? Perhaps with some clarification of 1), I could better understand 2)?

Comment: Lecture notes are here https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring12/sta104.1/Lectures/Lec15.pdf
esp. page 4)

Comment: on Slide 2, top left, the intuition behind the formula you report is explained: the pdf is calculated by imposing that the maximum falls in an infinitesimal range, and all the other values (of which  there are $z -1$)are less: the first part of the argument yields the pdf $f$, the second yields the cdf $F$.

Comment: With regards to 1), that is the cumulative distribution of the highest draw. The power of $z$ comes that all the (independent) draws have to be less than $x$.

Comment: (1) is CDF, discrete or continuous, (2) is PDF for continuous, differentiate (1) remembering that PDF $f(x)$ is derivative of CDF $F(x).$ Chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

The term *distribution* here must mean *distribution function*. So, if $X$ is a random variable, the distribution function is $F(x)=P(X \le x)$. When we are to find the distribution function of the maximum value obtained in $z$ independent realizations of $X$ what we really want to know is the distribution function of the random variable $max(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_z)$, that is:$$P(X_1 \le x, X_2\le x,\dots, X_z ,\le x)$$ which, by virtue of independence is $$P(X_1 \le x) \cdot P(X_2 \le x) \cdots P(X_z \le x)$$
and this equals $F(x)^z$.

The probability density function in the continuous case is obtained by differentiating the distribution function, so taking derivatives of  $F(x)^z$ and using $F^\prime(x)=f(x)$ you get the stated result.

Answer (score 0):

You asked specifically about the maximum observation $W$ among $n$ observations from $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$ for which the CDF is $F(x) = x,$ for $0 <x <1.$ So
$F_W(x) = x^n$ and $f_W(x) = nx^{n-1},$ which is the pdf of 
$\mathsf{Beta}(n, 1).$ (See [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) or your text.)

This is illustrated below by simulation of a million realizations with $n =   5$
in R statistical software.
The histogram approximates the distribution of $W.$ The red curve is the exact density of $\mathsf{Beta}(5,1).$

[image]

```
n = 5;  m = 10^6;  x = runif(m*n)
MAT = matrix(x, nrow=m)            # m x n matrix, each row a sample of 5
x = apply(MAT, 1, max)             # vector of m maximums
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2", 
     main="Approx Density of Max of 5 Std Uniforms")
  curve(dbeta(x, n, 1), lwd=2, col="red", add=T)
```